# Why is HttpClient catching connectivity errors?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've updated HttpClient and now it's no longer throwing `WebException` when it can't connect to the internet, breaking my handling of this situation.

Is this real? Is it a Xamarin.Forms framework feature? If so, how can I make it use the previous behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a major issue in the new .Net runtime. If you are writing a more robust solution you need to handle a few more scenarios in the `HttpClient` network calls.

1. First would be your case, where the network connectivity has been lost and an exception rises. A `TaskCancellationException` is thrown instead of `HttpRequestException`. As a workaround you can check the connectivity in catch and throw a custom exception from there.
2. When the request took longer than the specified timeout. This also is supposed to throw `HttpRequestException` but is currently throwing `TaskCancellationException` and has no internal exception that specifies that cause.
3. And the last would be, application canceling the request, this is also throwing `TaskCancellationException` which is correct but again there is no internal exception that specifies the cause. We need to check the task state manually and rethrow appropriately.

Now some code:

```cs
try
{
    return await action(cancellationToken);
}
catch(OperationCanceledException e) 
{
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // handle manual task cancellation
    }
    else
    {
        if (!connectivity.HasConnection)
        {
            // handle no connection
        }

        // handle time out
    }
}
```

More details about these bugs can be found at [#2196](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/21965) and [#35340](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/35340)

Answer (score 1):

It's throwing `TaskCanceledException` now. It’s also throwing `HttpRequestException` but without the inner `WebException`, which used to be there.

However, given that I'm using these exception handlers to check the internet connection upon an error, I figure I may as well catch and rethrow everything. Like this...

```
try
{
    return await action();
}
catch
{
    connectivityHelper.AssertConnected();

    throw;
}
```

If `AssertConnected` determines that there isn't an internet connection, it overrides the throw with its own throw of a custom `NoConnectivityException`.

Comment: Yes I caught the new exception.

Comment: Not for two days.